# issue with image uploading in the front end

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to implement image upload whereby a thumbnail appears alongside the buttons.. i have implemented it using function "getAsDataURL",... its not working in in chrome and safari.... any solution??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setImage(file) {
        if(document.all)
            document.getElementById('prevImage').src = file.value;
        else
            document.getElementById('prevImage').src = file.files.item(0).getAsDataURL();
        if(document.getElementById('prevImage').src.length > 0) 
            document.getElementById('prevImage').style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>


<div class="uploading_block_inner">
                                <div class="uploaded_img_inner"><img id="prevImage" style="display:none;" width="91" height="91" /></div>
                                <div class="submit_button_upload">
                                    <div class="upload"><input type="file" id=""  name="myImage" onchange="setImage(this);" /></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="upload_submit_inner"><input type="submit" name="" value="" /></div>                             
                            </div>
```

Comment: Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942105/file-data-from-input-element

Comment: I think the Mozilla non standard getAsDataURL function has not be accepted (and will be removed from firefox too).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery, I have following solution for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=file]').on('change', setImage);
});

function setImage(file) 
{
  if(document.all)
  {
    document.getElementById('prevImage').src = file.value;
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById('prevImage').src = file.files.item(0).getAsDataURL(); 
  }

  if(document.getElementById('prevImage').src.length > 0)
  {
    document.getElementById('prevImage').style.display = 'block'; 
  }
}
```

Comment: I added jQuery document ready event handling which was not there in original code