# How to read HTML file contents in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, file

I am sending data via ajax to post in mysql. In this context how to inlude image file contents ?

If i use like :
          var formData = document.getElementById("img_file");
          alert(formData.files[0]);

, i get error . Note : img_file is the id of the file dom. 
Any idea about this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942105/file-data-from-input-element

Comment: "i get error" – **What** error?!

Comment: @Quentin, i could not extract the file details from that data set. It was the real trouble and error.

Answer (score 5):

You can use javascript [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) for this purpose. Here is a sample code demonstration.

```html
<html>
    <body>

        <input type="file" id="fileinput" />
        <div id="ReadResult"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function readSingleFile(evt) {
                //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
                var f = evt.target.files[0];

                if (f) {
                    var r = new FileReader();
                    r.onload = function (e) {
                        var contents = e.target.result;
                        document.getElementById("ReadResult").innerHTML = contents;
                    }
                    r.readAsText(f);
                } else {
                    alert("Failed to load file");
                }
            }

            document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Find more details [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=L4k5y-rNufC).

Answer (score 0):

i think it may help you.

```
 $('#image').change(function () {
            $("#add").attr("disabled", true);
            var img = this.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader;
            reader.readAsDataURL(img);
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var file = new Image;
                file.src = e.target.result;
                file.onload = function () {
                    $("#height").text(file.height);
                    $("#width").text(file.width);
                    $("#imageprev").attr("src", file.src);
                    $("#upld").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            }

        });
```