# filename is undefined in the alert

Tags: javascript, html

Am unable to get the value of file chosen. In the alert box "undefined" value is getting displayed.
I need the value of the file and it needs to be stored in local. Can anyone please suggest.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgtuf.png

```
function Submitted() {
  let filename = document.getElementById('file1[]').files[0].name;
  for (let i = 0; i < filename.length; i++) {
    let abc = filename[i];
    kkk = "array[" + i + "].value= " + abc.value + " ";
    alert(kkk);
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="Submitted()">
  <input type="file" id="file1[]" name="file1" accept="image/*" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you expect `files[0].name` to be an array or array-like object?

Comment: Why do you expect `abc` to be an object with a `value` property?

Comment: Additional you will get ONE file returned per file input

Comment: `filename` is not array, it's string, so you are looping through letters of string, and `abc.value` does not make sense

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File data from input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942105/file-data-from-input-element)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are looping over the string that has the filename, not the array. And "abc" is a string, then ".value" does not make sense.

```
<form onsubmit="Submitted()">
  <input type="file" id="files" name="file1" accept="image/*" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
function Submitted() {
  let files = document.getElementById('files').files;
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    let abc = files[i];
    kkk = "array[" + i + "].value= " + abc.name + " ";
    alert(kkk);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting only the first value, rest of the choosen file from that loop value is not getting displayed

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the name of file in the filename variable.

The filename variable already contains the string name for the file.

You are trying to iterate over a string that is if the file name is "test.png", you are iterating over this text. Just alert the filename and you will get the name in the alert box. I have included a snippet so you can test it in the browser

```js
function submitted() {
  var filename = document.getElementById('file1[]').files[0].name;
  alert(filename);
}
```

```html
  <form onsubmit="submitted()">
    <input type="file" id="file1[]" name="file1" accept="image/*" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

As mentioned in comment, if you have multiple file upload controls in your form, you get get all the filenames by assigning them a class and iterating using the classname.

```js
function submitted() {
  var filenames = document.getElementsByClassName('uploadFiles');
  let files = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++)
  {
    files +=  "\n" +filenames[i].files[0].name;
  }
  alert(files);
}
```

```html
  <form onsubmit="submitted()">
    <input type="file" id="file1[]" class="uploadFiles" name="file1" accept="image/*"  />
    <input type="file" id="file1[]2" class="uploadFiles" name="file2" accept="image/*" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: `You are trying to iterate over on object that is not an array.` A string is iterated as an array. The cause of `undefined` is because of trying to access a `value` property of String which does not seem to be defined.

Comment: Yes my mistake, I corrected my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting only the first value. Rest of the values are not getting displayed

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? Are you trying to upload multiple images? Your snippet does not have the multiple attribute.

Comment: @DeepakThakur Yes, its in a dynamic value as it retrieves the table value from DB.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgtuf.png - Attached snapshot

Comment: Ok if you are using multiple upload input controls, just give them the same class and iterate over the classname instead of ids.  I have added a snipped to do the same. If you have just one image control that uploads multiple files, reply here I'll add a snipped for that too.